# How to delete document matching a query using official elasticsearch nodejs client?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I want to perform a `delete-by-query`, specifically delete all documents that have a field Kname that contains `Gary`. I am using the latest version of elasticsearch (2.3) I am using the official ES client:

```
elasticsearch-js
```

How can I perform such a deletion? Is it not supported? If not, appreciate any code/alternatives.

Comment: Which ES version are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest 2.3 for ES. Also using latest version of the elasticsearch-client.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you are on ES 2.x, delete-by-query is now a plugin, so you need to [install it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/plugins-delete-by-query.html) first and then also require the [deleteByQuery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch-deletebyquery) extension library for the Javascript client.

Then you can perform

```
    client.deleteByQuery({
        index: 'test',
        type: 'something',
        body: {
           query: {
               match: { Kname: 'gary' }
           }
        }
    }, function (error, response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: Why is it a plugin? This is to ES?

Comment: Yes, as of ES 2.0, [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_removed_features.html#_delete_by_query_is_now_a_plugin) is now a plugin that you have to install. Simply run `/bin/plugin install delete-by-query` and restart ES.

Comment: Have you been able to try this out?

Comment: In ES 5.4 no plugin needed.

Comment: no js plugin needed in latest version `"elasticsearch": "^16.3.0"`